# Custom validation alerts for jQuery Mobile Form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, mobile

I've got a form which uses the jQuery Validate Plugin to check for required fields before submission:

http://jsfiddle.net/2UYkY/1/

The default alert text that appears is "This field is required.". I would like to customise this for different fields but can't quite get it right - can anyone point out how to do this successfully.

I would typically add something like:

```
<label for = "username" class = "error">Please enter your Username</label> but this doesn't work correctly with this form.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope, this piece of code would be of any help. One can put custom error messages for each & every field under messages.

```
$("#aspnetForm").validate({

   errorLabelContainer: "#errorMessages",
   rules: {
    name: {
            required: true,
            validChars: true
        },
    email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          },
    lname:{
            required: true,
            validChars: true
          },
    zip: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            digits: true
          },
    },      
    messages: {
        email:"custom error message",
        name:"custom error message",
        lname:"custom error message",
        zip:"custom error message"
    }
  });
```